# Error in MultipleRingBuffer_analysis in python

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, error-000735

I'm trying to use Value table in python to do a multiple ring buffer in ArcGIS 10.1 and I'm getting the following error:
ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000735: Distances: Value is required
Failed to execute (MultipleRingBuffer).

Here's the code:

```py
arcpy.env.workspace = Path
vTab = arcpy.ValueTable()
vTab.setRow = (0, "2")
vTab.setRow = (1, "10")
vTab.setRow = (2, "50")
inFeature = 'Test.shp'
outFeaute = 'Test_Output.shp'
dist = vTab
bufferUnit = "meters"
arcpy.MultipleRingBuffer_analysis(inFeature, outFeaute, dist, bufferUnit, '','ALL')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were a few syntax errors with the code. Rather than attempt to explain each one I have rewritten your code to show you how you should have written it. The main problem is that your `vTab` object was not being correctly updated.

```py
arcpy.env.workspace = "c:/temp"
vTab = arcpy.ValueTable(1)
vTab.addRow(2)
vTab.addRow(10)
vTab.addRow(50)
inFeature = 'myPointLayer'
outFeature = 'Test_Output.shp'
bufferUnit = "Meters"
arcpy.MultipleRingBuffer_analysis(inFeature, outFeature, vTab, bufferUnit, 'distance','ALL')
```